# How to render Array data, which is taken into a Array variable from Google Sheet API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Array variable, which gets data from the Google Sheet API. I want to render data in some specific page and show data fro that array.

```
//app.js Code

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var routes = require('./routes');
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

//Google SHeet API

app.get('/excel',routes.excel);

//index.js Code

//Google Sheet API
exports.excel=(req,res)=>{
  const {google} = require ('googleapis');
const keys = require('../keys.json');

const client = new google.auth.JWT(
        keys.client_email, null,keys.private_key,
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
);

client.authorize(function(err, tokens){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }else{
      console.log('Connected');
      gsrun(client);
    }

   });
   async function gsrun(cl){
  const gsapi = google.sheets({
    version:'v4',auth:cl});
    const opt = {
      spreadsheetId:'1cPNCt3mTyYN3Mor7S6CPxzCJFfHwVKF3jgzF31fp0jM',
      range: 'Data!A2:B5'
    };
    var data = await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(opt);
    var dataArray =data.data.values;
    console.log(dataArray);
     }
    res.render('excel',{
    title:"My Google Sheet API",
    dataArray:dataArray
      });
    }


    // final excel.ejs Page


   <li><%= dataArray.lenght %></li>
```

I got an error in index.js page dataArrey in not defined. I want to show Data from my Google Sheet to excel.ejs page by rendering dataArray. However, I got console log data.

Comment: Please post all of your code.

Comment: Revised Code has been edited, please help me